# Using flush() before close()

Tags: java, iostream

As per the java docs, invoking close() on any java.io Streams automatically invokes flush(). But I have seen in lot of examples, even in production codes, developers have explicitly  used  flush() just before close(). In what conditions we need to use flush() just before close()?

Comment: This question may help you a little bit [see this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300676/when-to-use-flush-in-java

Comment: @Siva: `as per the Javadoc`. Quote and link, or it doesn't exist. As far as I know, *some* stream implementations will flush on close, while others won't. Do prove me wrong if that's not the case and the Javadoc says otherwise.

Comment: Same question as haylem. I read through Java API documentation of a few classes and some say that `flush()` is called in `close()` while others don't make any such comment. Any link?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Developer get into a habit of calling flush() after writing something which must be sent.

IMHO Using flush() then close() is common when there has just been a write e.g.

```
// write a message
out.write(buffer, 0, size);
out.flush();

// finished
out.close();
```

As you can see the flush() is redundant, but means you are following a pattern.

Comment: redundant + pattern = anti-pattern?

Comment: Depending on the implenting class this might not be redundant. E.g if someinterface.getOutputStream() returns an OutputStream, you might not know if the close method calls flush or if the flush method is empty, if it's not explicitly documented. E.g. URLConnection.getOutputStream(): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getOutputStream--

Answer (score 32):

I guess in many cases it's because they don't know `close()` also invokes `flush()`, so they want to be safe.

Anyway, using a buffered stream should make manual flushing almost redundant.

Comment: Upvoted. Anybody, actually, should not assume that all `close()` also invokes `flush()`.

Comment: @JinKwon They are perfectly entitled to do that for any output stream that extends `FilterOutputStream`: see the Javadoc.

Comment: The statement "they don't know close() also invokes flush()" is misleading, it's *not* always the case.

Answer (score 11):

I want to point out an important concept that many previous comments have alluded to:

A stream's `close()` method does *NOT necessarily* invoke `flush()`.

For example [org.apache.axis.utils.ByteArray](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/axis/utils/ByteArray.java.html)#close() does not invoke `flush()`.
 (click link to see source code)

The same is true more generally for any implementations of `Flushable` and `Closeable`. A prominent example being [java.io.PrintWriter](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/io/PrintWriter.java#l334). Its `close()` method does NOT call `flush()`.
(click link to see source code)

This might explain why developers are cautiously calling `flush()` before closing their streams. I personally have encountered production bugs in which `close()` was called on a PrintWriter instance without first calling `flush()`.

Comment: Both examples provided are essentially thin wrapper classes, so their `flush` and `close` implementations delegate to the underlying stream. I can't see how this alone could lead to any problems, as long as any "real" or buffering streams do flush when being closed.

Comment: However I realize that the behavior is not (and can't be) enforced by the javadoc of `Closeable.close()`.

Answer (score 4):

The answers already provided give interesting insights that I will try to compile
here.

`Closeable` and `Flushable` being two independent traits, `Closeable` do not specify that `close()` should call `flush()`. This means that it is up to the implementation's documentation (or code) to specify whether `flush()` is called or not. In most cases it is the norm, but there is no guaranty.

Now regarding what @Fabian wrote: It is true that `java.io.PrintWriter`'s `close()` method does not call `flush()`. However it calls `out.close()` (`out` being the underlying writer). Assuming `out` is a `BufferedWriter`, we are fine since `BufferedWriter.close()` is flushing (according to its doc). Had it be another writer, it may not have been the case...

So you have two choices:

- either you ensure that at least one inner Writer/Stream flushes by itself (beware in case of code refactoring),
- or you just call `flush()` and you're on the safe side all the time.

Solution 2, requiring less work, is my preferred one.

Comment: True, but not all `Closable` specifies it.  For instance, `OutputStream` does not.