# Java: Blank File on writing

Tags: java, file, file-io, io

I am trying to write to a file in Java using the following function:

```
public void writeTextFile(String filename, double s){
  FileWriter output=null;
  try{
    output= new FileWriter(filename);
    BufferedWriter writer=new BufferedWriter(output);
    String ss = String.valueOf(s);
    writer.write(ss);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  } finally {
    if (output != null) {
      try {
        output.flush();
        output.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {

      }
    }
  }
}
```

I also tried using:

```
FileOutputStream out;
PrintStream prt;
try{
  out= new FileOutputStream("result");
  prt=new PrintStream(out);
  prt.println(value);
  prt.flush();
  prt.close();
}
catch(Exception e){
  System.out.println("File write error");}
```

But i end up with a blank output file with both the methods. Need help!!:(

Comment: it works fine... are you assigning 'value' ??

Comment: try adding writer.flush and writer.close in 1st code.

Comment: What is printed if you add `System.out.println("value: '" + value + "'");`?

Comment: @DarthCoder : value=esa.getRelatedness(args[0], args[1]);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work,

```
public void writeTextFile(String filename, double s){
 FileWriter output=null;
 try{
  output= new FileWriter(filename);
  BufferedWriter writer=new BufferedWriter(output);
  String ss = String.valueOf(s);
  writer.append(ss);
  writer.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
  throw new RuntimeException(e);
} finally {
  if (output != null) {
  try {
    output.flush();
    output.close();
  } catch (IOException e) {

  }
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey its simple the error is that you aren't flushing the bufferedwriter please do that before you flush and close the stream.

add this to your first code

```
public static void writeTextFile(String filename, double s){
        FileWriter output=null;
        try{
            output= new FileWriter(filename);
            BufferedWriter writer=new BufferedWriter(output);
            String ss = String.valueOf(s);
            System.out.println("ss:"+ss);
            writer.write(ss);
            writer.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (output != null) {
                try {
                    output.flush();
                    output.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Adding *close()* works. Flush before close is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

try this

use this link :
[Tutorial on file writing](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-to-file-in-java-bufferedwriter-example/)

Code from the link :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            String content = "This is the content to write into file";

            File file = new File("/users/mkyong/filename.txt");

            // if file doesnt exists, then create it
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(content);
            bw.close();

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with instantiating a `FileWriter` directly using the filename. Using `File` is not necessary.

Comment: you are correct , its another option not necessary ... Edited.

Comment: You don't need to call createNewFile(). Poor quality tutorial.

Answer (score -2):

What if you try:

```
File file = new File("c:/newfile.txt");
    String content = "This is the text content";

    try (FileOutputStream fop = new FileOutputStream(file)) {

        // if file doesn't exists, then create it
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        // get the content in bytes
        byte[] contentInBytes = content.getBytes();

        fop.write(contentInBytes);
        fop.flush();
        fop.close();

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Based on this tutorial: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-to-file-in-java-fileoutputstream-example/

Comment: You don't need to call createNewFile(), or flush before closing. Poor quality tutorial.

Comment: @EJP no need to downvote, they're just patterns (it's not a poor qualit tutorial). Read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620683/java-fileoutputstream-create-file-if-not-exists and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9858495/using-flush-before-close

Answer (score -2):

You have to flush and close BufferedWriter not FileWriter.

Comment: While this is correct, it's already been said (and accepted) by others. You should only answer if it adds something that someone else hasn't said.

Comment: And you don't have to flush, only close.