# Should I also flush() a stream when I'm done with it, or is close() enough?

Tags: java, io

After I'm done using a BufferedWriter, I know I should call `writer.close()`. But should I also call `writer.flush()`? Or is it unnecessary?

Also, does it matter if I do this inside the `try` block containing the instantiation of the stream and the IO code - or outside of it?

Comment: @BackSlash You're right, I meant writer.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9858495/using-flush-before-close)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close will automatically flush your stream, so yoou dont have to flush the stream while closing. Flush is useful when you are in the middle of writing to a stream and want to push the intermediate values to the file/output stream, so that if the program crashes the data wont be lost.

From Java 7 and higher you can make use of [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to avoid writing the clean up code for cleaning up the streams.

> The try-with-resources statement is a try statement that declares one or more resources. A resource is an object that must be closed after the program is finished with it. The try-with-resources statement ensures that each resource is closed at the end of the statement.

Comment: Does it matter if I call writer/reader.close() inside or outside of the `try` block containing the IO code and the writer/reader instantiation?

Comment: If you are using JDK 7 and aboe, use try with resource, that will save you the effort of writing the code to cleanup/close the stream.

Comment: Thanks, but anyway could you answer my last question?

Comment: ideally stream should be closed in finally block so that even if there is some exception it will be closed in the finally block.

Answer (score 3):

From what I've experienced, you should call `flush` only when you want/need to make sure the current data must be written in the stream. When you work with small files, you will just call `close` directly since this already triggers a flush on the file stream before writing it. But when you work with bigger files e.g. a file having 1 million lines or more, then it would be better calling `flush` from time to time (e.g. after writing 10k lines), in order to write to disk and ease the final `flush` called by `close`. This can be done in case the program crashes.

Answer (score 2):

The Methode close() will call (f)flush() automatic