# Difficulty writing downloaded pdf file to android device

Tags: io, kotlin, okhttp, android-file

I am downloading a pdf file from a web server using okhttp.  The file appears to download correctly, and the file "Test.pdf" is created.  The file size is listed as 0 however in the Device File Explorer in Android Studio.

Here is my callback code:

```
client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {

    override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                    println("Failed")
                }

    override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {

                    println("Success!")

                    val file = File(filesDir, "Test.pdf")
                    println(response.body()!!.bytes().size)

                    file.outputStream().write(response.body()!!.bytes())
                    file.outputStream().flush()
                    file.outputStream().close()
                }
            })
```

The println statement shows the correct file size of 6MB.  I am really unsure why the file is not writing to the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're opening a new `OutputStream` with every new call of the `outputStream` function. Instead, you can use just one:

```
val os = file.outputStream()
os.write(response.body()!!.bytes())
os.flush()
os.close()
```

And you might wanna wrap it in a [`use`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/use.html) block instead of closing it yourself (and [flushing it isn't necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31456660/fileoutputstream-does-the-close-method-calls-also-flush)):

```
file.outputStream().use { os ->
    os.write(response.body()!!.bytes())
}
```

And if you only need to write a single `ByteArray`, the [`writeBytes`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/write-bytes.html) method that was already suggested by @ice1000 does the above with even less code:

```
file.writeBytes(response.body()!!.bytes())
```

---

And while here, I'd perform a `null` check on the response body just to be safe:

```
val responseBytes = response.body()?.bytes()
if (responseBytes != null) {
    file.writeBytes(responseBytes)
} else {
    // Handle error somehow
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this very comprehensive answer.  For whatever reason I was treating file.outputStream() like it was a singleton...rookie mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe there's a simpler way (also less efficient, but don't worry about small files, it's already very fast):

```
File(filesDir, "Test.pdf").writeBytes(URL("your url").readBytes())
```

`writeBytes` and `readBytes` are Kotlin stdlib extension functions.

Comment: This works thank you.  I gave the answer credit to @zsmb13 because his answer was like a tutorial.