# Trying to write the data to a .txt file. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, file

I want to write data- the time it takes for a function to run- to a .txt file so that I can take it to Excel and make a spreadsheet (it's possible to make log-log and semi-log graphs in Excel).

**Here's what I have so far:
timing.java**

```
  public static void main(String args[]) {

        Stopwatch timeMe = new Stopwatch();

    ...

    try
    {
        File logFile = new File("log.txt");
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(logFile2, true);
        FileWriter fw2 = new FileWriter(logFile, true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

        // if file doesnt exists, then create it
        if (!logFile.exists()) {
            logFile.createNewFile();
            System.out.println("doesn't exist");
        }
    ...

        for (int i = 1000; i <= 256000; i+=1000)
        {
            int[] randomArray = randomarr(i);
            fw.write(String.valueOf(i));
            fw.write(String.format("%n"));
            timeMe.start();
            pluto(randomArray);
            timeMe.stop();
            fw.write(timeMe.toString());
            fw.write(String.format("%n"));
        }
    }

    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
...
}
```

**Stopwatch.java**

```
/**
 A class to measure time elapsed.
*/

public class Stopwatch
{
    private long startTime;
    private long stopTime;

    public static final double NANOS_PER_SEC = 1000000000.0;

    /**
     start the stop watch.
    */
    public void start()
    {   System.gc();
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
    }

    /**
     stop the stop watch.
    */
    public void stop()
    {   stopTime = System.nanoTime();   }

    /**
    elapsed time in secods.
    @return the time recorded on the stopwatch in seconds
    */
    public double time()
    {   return (stopTime - startTime) / NANOS_PER_SEC;  }

    public String toString()
    {   return "elapsed time: " + time() + " seconds."; }

    /**
    elapsed time in nanoseconds.
    @return the time recorded on the stopwatch in nanoseconds
    */
    public long timeInNanoseconds()
    {   return (stopTime - startTime);  }
}
```

The problem is, when I change anything in Stopwatch, i.e. remove the "elapsed time: " and " seconds." in the .toString() method to isolate the numbers, nothing will print to the file. In other words, the .txt file is empty. When I run it using the original Stopwatch.java file, everything is printed to the log.txt file, but I don't want this text.

Comment: Writers MUST be closed. Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: Why are there two files? And why aren't you writing to the second one? And why have you mixed up the names so that `fw = logfile2` and *vice versa?*

Answer (score 2):

Do you close the file, and/or [flush it explicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9858495/1426891)? If not, your data may be buffered but unwritten when your program terminates.

It may be working until you remove the surrounding characters simply because you've generated enough text to automatically trigger a file write.

Related: [BufferedWriter not writing everything to its output file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13426142/1426891)

Answer (score 1):

```
FileWriter fw2 = new FileWriter(logFile, true);
```

Here you have created a file called whatever is in `logFile`.

```
// if file doesnt exists, then create it
if (!logFile.exists()) {
    logFile.createNewFile();

    System.out.println("doesn't exist");
}
```

Here you have overwritten it with another one. If you're on Unix, Linux, etc., `fw2` will continue to write to the previous file, but it has been deleted so you will never see the data. Remove this entire block.

Comment: This is definitely good advice to follow, but I do see that the OP orphans the file pointed to by `fw2` (`logFile`) and not `fw` (to which he writes). Either way I'm not sure how this would be affected by an isolated change in a `toString()` method.