# Calling close() on OutputStream is cutting off output to a log file

Tags: java, io, stream

I was looking into a problem with `.close()` causing cut-off issues. The program is running on two different servers, but had the same cutoff issue. It appears that the log file is not flushing properly. So I decided to dig into the `.close()` source code. I don't see a `.flush()` being called. Am I missing something? Should we always call `.flush()`? According to this answer, it shouldn't matter: [Using flush() before close()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9858495/using-flush-before-close)

What I'm calling:

```
    private static void write_to_file(String incoming){
    output_stream.write(incoming);
    output_stream.write(System.lineSeparator());
    }
```

Later on I call `output_stream.close();`

The source code:

```
 /**
 * Closes the stream and releases any system resources associated
 * with it. Closing a previously closed stream has no effect.
 *
 * @see #checkError()
 */
public void close() {
    try {
        synchronized (lock) {
            if (out == null)
                return;
            out.close();
            out = null;
        }
    }
    catch (IOException x) {
        trouble = true;
    }
}
```

Log file:

> ```
> C:\apps\bot\log\processed\file.0000090.gz
> C:\apps\bot\log\processed\file.0000091.gz
> C:\apps\bot\log\process
> ```

Comment: Using `close()` should be all you need. How do you create the stream you are writing to? Are you absolutely sure that your `close()` method gets called?

Comment: You know what, I had just checked that and saw it was only being executed in a try-catch block (on any exception). Please leave an answer and I will mark correct. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9858495/2032064) you've correctly pointed out, calling `close()` on a stream is enough to flush whatever you've written to the stream. If the output is truncated, there are a few common pitfalls:

- Your `close()` method is not called, e.g. if you put it in a `catch` block instead of `finally` ;)
- Calling `close()` on a custom stream doesn't propagate the call to the underlying stream.
- The problem can also be in encoding if you don't properly convert your String to bytes.