# Downloading file using java (Showing invalid characters in downloaded file)

Tags: java, file, file-io, download, fileinputstream

I'm trying to download a file using java, file is downloading but showing invalid characters in a file as shown in below.

Same thing with the images too, Showing invalid image.

Everything looks fine, Did i missed something? or Anybody having better solution than this?

**index.jsp**

```
<body>  
     Click on the link to download:
     <a href="download.jsp">Download Link</a>
</body>
```

**download.jsp**

```
<%
try {
    String filename = "C:/slcmimages/StudentDetails.xls"; // jpg, png, doc etc
    response.setContentType("APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);

    // transfer the file byte-by-byte to the response object
    File fileToDownload = new File(filename);
    response.setContentLength((int) fileToDownload.length());
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileToDownload);
    int i = 0;
    while ((i = fileInputStream.read()) != -1) {
        out.write(i);
    }
    fileInputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
%>
```

**Actual File:**

[image]

**File after downloading:**

[image]

Comment: Can you try with response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");

Comment: @dasrohith file can be of any format like xls, jpg, png etc..

Comment: Have you tried with vnd.ms-excel content type?

Comment: @dasrohith yes.. showing the same

Comment: Don't set the content-length. JSP or the servlet container should do that for you.

Comment: You should `close()` your streams in the [`finally`-block, not in `try`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7300778/2056452), to ensure the execution.

Comment: Your picture of the 'actual file' is an Excel screenshot. Your picture of the download isn't. There is no evidence here that this file doesn't open in Excel, or that there is any problem to solve.