# Serialize an existing Java object with circular dependencies

Tags: java, serialization, jax-rs

I have an object from a class I cannot modify.

The object has a circular dependency.

I would like to serialize the object, but I don't have access to java source code, as it's in a library.

In C++ I could create a subclass, override the virtual methods, then cast down to get the desired behavior. In Java this is not possible.

What options do I have besides creating a new POJO class and copying over every field by hand?

Comment: So the object's not `Serializable` I presume.

Comment: No, it's not...

Comment: You can use reflection and copy all fields recursively, while using an `IdentityHashMap` for resolving cycles. However, I'm sure, someone already did it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5294224/581205

Answer (score 0):

Serialization using Serializable is a bit smelly anyway. I'd prefer using an external serializer, using either JSON (e.g. [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson), [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson)) or a binary format (e.g. [Kryo](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo)). Either way, you can write custom serializers in all of these that resolve your circular dependencies.

Comment: How do you resolve circular dependencies without annotating the class?

Comment: All of the technologies I listed support external serializers that resolve the dependencies externally. How you do it is up to you, but examples would be to serialize a List of Objects as a List of Object IDs, and deserialize it again by loading those objects by these IDs from your persistence layer

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: No, but those websites I linked to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'd opt for [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson/blob/master/README.md), even if you are going to be the only one reading/writing your objects. Many advantages, up to and including:

1. Diagnosing/debugging the serialized JSON makes life easy.
2. Staying on this well-trodden path means solutions to any questions are a Google away, e.g., http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization