# Does Jackson internally use java serialization or is it completely independent?

Tags: java, serialization, jdbc, jackson

I read the answer for alternatives for java serialization given below.

[Which is the best alternative for Java Serialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239280/which-is-the-best-alternative-for-java-serialization)

I am in doubt that are these options truly independent of java serialization or are they built on java serialization.
If not then how do they work internally?

Comment: This question is way too broad. And most (all?) projects you mention are open source, so if you want to know how they work internally, you can inspect their source code.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very open question as you're putting various APIs / serialisation techniques into the same category. I'll only respond to the JDBC part, in case of which obviously none of the drivers use Java serialisation because the relevant database communication protocols are defined by the databases independently of any client technology (Java, PHP, .NET, Python, etc...).

It would be safe to assume that most similar API implementations work in a similar fashion behind the scenes, because Java serialisation is inherently Java-specific, and it is usually not a good idea to make any protocol (regardless of the purpose) language-specific.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on JDBC. Could you comment more about the other third party API mentioned.

Comment: @ShubhamKadlag: No, they're a seemingly random list of APIs and I don't have any experience with them. Someone else can comment on them...